# replace not working in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have simple string

```
 const string = 'or id 671674205=##=2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass3 [DEBUG] detail for id 2146263624=##=2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass1 [TRACE] verbose detail for id 619472373=##=2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass5 [TRACE] verbose detail for id 1391429871=##=2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass1 [DEBUG] detail for id 1522968690=##=2'
```

I want to replace `=##=` with `<br/>`  and tried this

```
string.replace(/=##=/g, '<br/>')
console.log(string)
```

But didn't work... Please help to resolve this

Comment: Shouldn't it be `string = string.replace(/=##=/g, 'aaa')`.

Comment: thank you that was the issue... You can post it as answer I will accept

Comment: you can tick anyone's answer as long as it serves your purpose.

Comment: Ok thanks once again... And if some downvotes the question please mention the reason in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript String are immutable.  You cannot alter a string.  String operations `trim` `slice` `replace` return a new string. You can do this

```
const myString = string.replace(/=##=/g, '<br/>');
console.log(myString);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign modified `string` to original `string` due to this you will have to change `const` to `let` or you can save in other `variable`.

```js
let string = 'or id 671674205=##=2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass3 [DEBUG] detail for id 2146263624=##=2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass1 [TRACE] verbose detail for id 619472373=##=2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass5 [TRACE] verbose detail for id 1391429871=##=2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass1 [DEBUG] detail for id 1522968690=##=2';

string = string.replace(/=##=/g, 'aaa')
console.log(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

From MDN docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

> The `replace()` method returns a new string with some or all matches of
>   a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a
>   RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called
>   for each match.

```js
let string = 'or id 671674205=##=2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass3 [DEBUG] detail for id 2146263624=##=2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass1 [TRACE] verbose detail for id 619472373=##=2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass5 [TRACE] verbose detail for id 1391429871=##=2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass1 [DEBUG] detail for id 1522968690=##=2';
console.log("original string");
console.log(string)

string = string.replace(/=##=/g, 'aaa')
console.log("Updated string");
console.log(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `replace()` method returns the replaced string that matches the given regex. In your code you are missing to overwrite the value of `string` variable with the replaced one as you are expecting the replaced value to be in `string`variable. Thus you need to do

```
//assign replaced value to `string` and overwrite the old value
string = string.replace(/=##=/g, '<br/>');
console.log(string)
```